# bash array yields array_name[@] at index 0

Tags: arrays, bash

I am trying to store in a Look-Up-Table(sine) sin(x) values normalized between 0 and 255, with x being mapped from [0; 2Pi] to [0; 255], all integers. However when using trying to access the 0th or 256th index it shows up soemtimes as `sine[@]`

```
#! /bin/bash
function load_sin {
    sine=${1}[@]
    PI=3.14159
    for angle in {0..256}
    do  
        sine[$angle]=$(awk "BEGIN{ printf \"%8.0f \", ((sin($angle*($PI/128))*255))}")
    done
}
function sin {
    sine=${1}[@]
    angle=$(($2%256))
    echo "from sin function :sine[$angle] = ${sine[$angle]}"
}

declare -a sine
load_sin sine
for angle in {0..255}
do
    echo -n "from main scope : ${sine[$(($angle%255))]}  "
    sin sine $(($angle))
done
```

output is the following:

```
#from main scope :        0   from sin function :sine[0] = sine[@]
#from main scope :        6   from sin function :sine[1] =        6 
#from main scope :       13   from sin function :sine[2] =       13 
#...
#from main scope :      -25   from sin function :sine[252] =      -25 
#from main scope :      -19   from sin function :sine[253] =      -19 
#from main scope :      -13   from sin function :sine[254] =      -13 
#from main scope : sine[@]  from sin function :sine[255] =       -6
```

What I'd like to return is in every case: 
`sine[255] = -6` 
and 
`sine [0] = 0`

Comment: Paste your script into [ShellCheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: ...what do you expect `sine=${1}[@]` to mean or do? If you want an indirect reference to an array, that's what `declare -n` is for.

Comment: ...but then, if this question evolves down to "how do I indirectly reference an array?", there are duplicates we can close it with.

Comment: Keep in mind that **shell variables aren't local unless you make them so**. When you set `sine=${1}[@]}`, you're changing `${sine[0]}` because changing the first element of an array is what assigning to that array *does*.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Okay, but could you please elaborate on what is wrong? I'm a beginner bash scripting and I don't get what is wrong on line 3 and 11

Comment: You're assuming that we know what you thought lines 3 and 11 would do when you wrote them. I made some guesses, but they're just that -- *guesses*. I can tell you what they *actually* do with a great deal of certainty, but only you can speak to your intent.

Comment: @Soulthym You can also change `sine=${1}[@]` to `sine=$@`. (but defer to Charles' answer -- every time...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because (1) bash variables are all global unless explicitly declared otherwise (so `sine` inside your function refers to the `sine` array declared outside of it); and (2) assigning a string to an array changes the first element of that array.

Thus, when you run:

```
sine=${1}[@]
```

...that's exactly identical to:

```
sine[0]=${1}[@]
```

So when you call `load_sin sine`, `$1` is the string `"sine"`, so  the assignment assigns the string `sine[@]` to the first element of the array `sine`.

---

Compare to the following, which does proper indirect references and assignments (albeit as noops when `sine` is the exact variable name provided):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

load_sin() {
    # if our first argument is not "sine", make sine a reference to the variable thus-named
    [[ $1 != sine ]] && declare -n sine=$1

    while read -r angle value; do
      sine[$angle]=$value
    done < <(awk -v PI=3.14159 -v start=0 -v end=256 '
      BEGIN {
        for(angle=start; angle<end; angle++) {
          printf "%d %8.0f \n", angle, sin(angle*(PI/128))*255
        }
      }')
}

sin() {
    [[ $1 != sine ]] && declare -n sine=$1

    angle=$(($2%256))
    echo "from sin function :sine[$angle] = ${sine[$angle]}"
}

declare -a sine
load_sin sine
for angle in {0..255}
do
    printf '%s' "from main scope : ${sine[$(($angle%255))]}  "
    sin sine $(($angle))
done
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much I had no idea it was passed as a string, that works perfectly

Comment: BTW, we could probably make `load_sin` much faster by running `awk` just once and printing all 256 values, instead of calling a separate awk once per value. Let me know if you're interested in that, and I might try to throw it together.

Comment: @Soulthym, ...so, I ended up doing that edit anyhow; hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Anything that's not built into the shell itself has a significant startup cost just to `fork()` off a subprocess and then call `execve()` to replace that forked-off copy of the shell with whatever the external program is (which needs to have its libraries linked and loaded, etc). It's not that big for a one-off, but if you're doing something in a loop -- even just calling `/bin/true` 256 times is more than half a second on my local box, and `awk` is larger than `true` with more dependencies.

Comment: well thank you, why not actually, I didn't know awk was that long to invoke

Comment: Runtime was very low for me so I didn't think about speeding it up, especially for setting up a LookUpTable, but that's probably much faster.
time before this modification:
```real    0m0,000s  
user    0m0,000s  
sys     0m0,000s  
```
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I wonder how you're measuring -- I get 3.5s for the old method, and 0.077s for the new one on my local Mac (with output printed to the console, which takes some time). ideone.com, by contrast, shows 0.264s for the old and 0.031 for the new, with output suppressed in both cases, at https://ideone.com/l87Y66

Comment: looks like vim preloaded something, I ran ```:!time %``` in it to get 0.000s, 
without vim I get 0.025s for the new method and ```real    0m0,685s
real    0m0,010s``` with yours